# Read multiple CSVs, calculate Mean and write it into a new CSV

Tags: python, csv

i have multiple CSV lets say like 10

in Every CSV there are 2 Values (Coordinates) and the last value eg. -89 is a meassured value.

```
0,0,-89
1,0,-89
2,0,-89
3,0,-89
4,0,-89
5,0,-89
6,0,-88
7,0,-88
8,0,-88
9,0,-88
10,0,-88
11,0,-88
12,0,-88
13,0,-88
```

I want to go over these 10 CSVs read each row for the meassured Value count the mean and write it into a new CSV. So the Programm should read like each row and count the mean and put the mean into a new CSV. It should look like 0,0,-87.99933 for example.

One CSV has 5356 rows.

Im currently struggeling how to write a Programm to do this task any idea / tip how to do that

So i want i want to do is: read first row of file 1, read first row of file 2 and count the mean of the meassured value eg. -89

Thanks

Comment: so what have you tried? ([so] is not some magic oracle which does your homework)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? please post the code that you have tried

Comment: Do you just want the first coordinate from each file as the output coordinates?

Comment: Look into [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html). You can read each CSV with `pd.read_csv()`, calculate the mean, and save with the `to_csv()` method.

Comment: Thanks, i didnt know about pandas at all will look into it

Comment: So with  `for a in range (1,11,1):
   row= pandas.read_csv("test" +str(a) +".csv")
   print row` he reads all the 10 test csv and prints me the information how can i now cut the first to values and only pick up the meassured value eg. -89?

Comment: No need for Pandas, Python has a csv module complete with file readers/writers: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

csv_file_list = ["file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv"]
result_csv = "result.csv"

with open(result_csv, 'wb') as rf:
    for idx, csv_file in enumerate(csv_file_list):
        csv_data = pd.read_csv(csv_file).values
        mean_measured = np.mean(csv_data[:, 2])
        rf.write(','.join([str(0), str(idx), str(mean_measured)+"\n"]))
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer. Does this Programm count the mean of every File? Because what i want to do is: read first row of file 1, read first row of file 2... and then count the mean. And that for 5356 rows. I think this Programm counts it for every file?

Comment: No it calculates the mean of the measurement column of each file and store it as a row in a results file. It was difficult to understand from the question what exactly you want to do. In your case create a for loop from 0 to 5356, calculate the mean for each row and write it to a result file.

Comment: Okay, but how can calculate it for each row?

Comment: I ussume that `mean_measured = np.mean(csv_data[:, 2])` the 2 stands for the 3rd column right?

Comment: Yes, 2 stands for the 3rd column.

Comment: And how can i adress the row?

Comment: [:, 2] it is Not clear to me why there ist a Double Point comma

Comment: Double Point comma means iterate over all rows. This is numpy specific way of handling matrix data (very similar to the handling in Matlab)